# Fetchmail disconnecting on SSL mismatch

Tags: ssl, certificates, fetchmail

My fetchmail (v6.4.24) is connecting to an MTA that holds mail for many domains, and it has certs for each domain.  The MTA (running dovecot) expects the client to use TLS SNI to present the right certificate to the client.

It seems fetchmail does not support TLS SNI, so dovecot just presents the first cert setup in the config file, and that results in a SSL cert mismatch when fetchmail tries to retrieve mail.  However, I am NOT using the --sslcertck command line option, nor the sslcertck run control file option, so (according the docs) fetchmail should continue processing.  Yet is fails as shown below:

```
fetchmail: Server CommonName mismatch: mta.fqdn1 != mta.fqdn2
fetchmail: mta.fqdn2 key fingerprint: 85:11:19:4A:2B:C0:D7:68:85:5F:52:CC:B8:2A:C5:61
fetchmail: Server certificate verification error: hostname mismatch
fetchmail: OpenSSL reported: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed
fetchmail: mta.fqdn2: SSL connection failed.
```

Why is fetchmail disconnecting upon this error?  Is there an rc file option to ignore the cert and continue?

My fetchmail rc entry is as follows:

```
poll mta.fdqn1
proto pop3
bad-header accept
user user@fqdn1
pass pass
smtpname 'user@fqdn1'
smtphost 1.2.3.4/940
options ssl
fetchall
antispam 501
nokeep
dropdelivered
```

Comment: *"It seems fetchmail does not support TLS SNI"* - fetchmail has support for SNI since 6.4.0, released about 4 years ago. See https://sourceforge.net/p/fetchmail/mailman/message/36773211/ (and search for SNI). Since you are running a version with support for SNI the problem might be something else. You can do a packet capture (like with wireshark) to make sure that the server_name is presented in the ClientHello.